# calling .each() function in jquery script

Tags: jquery, each

I have some html elements, and jquery that properly updates elements values at the moment of document loaded.

This looks like:

```
$('.elem_text, .elem_text10').each(function() {
.... 
}
```

After i want to do following:

I want to update value of element, that new value is interned, and i need to refresh values again, for that i want to trigger each function from another function, or otherwise i will just have to copy the code to another function.

I can't find any possibility how to trigger each() function, methods that i tried does not work:

```
function updateElements() {
  ....
     !  $('#elem_id').trigger("each");  // <- does not work 
     !  $('#elem_id').each();           // <- does not work
}
```

Maybe anybody has own suggestions how to implement function?

Or i still should copy the code 2 times?

Urmas Repinski.

Comment: When do you want to refresh the values?
as mentioned below each is not an event. However you will need an event to trigger your function.

Answer (score 0):

Each isn't an event! It's just an asynchronous iterator. Refactor the code in the each out to a function and then reuse it in your updateElements. Post a JSFiddle and I can help you further.

Comment: I'm pretty sure `each` is synchronous, although the work you do in the closure may be asynchronous.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('body').delegate('#elem_id','click',function(){
   $('.elem_text, .elem_text10').each(function() {
   .... 
   }
});
```

What I did here is I wrapped your code in an event. Everytime #elem_id is clicked it will run your code. as I'm not sure when you want to update the values I just went with the "click"